# Problems with pathlib iterdir()

Tags: python, pathlib

For my project, I read a line of input from my text file that reads "D C:/Test/Project1".  The D signifies to print the files in the directory, ignoring subdirectories.  "R" signifies to print the files in the directory and every subdirectory.  The specific directory follows the letter after a space. The directory contains a few python files.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

infile = open("input.txt", "r")


def subfolder(p):
    contents = p.iterdir()
    for i in contents:
        if i.is_file(): 
            print(i)
        elif i.is_dir():
            subfolder(i)        

for line in infile:
    if line[0] == "R":
        p = Path(str(line[2:]))
        contents = p.iterdir()
        for i in contents:
            print(i)
            if i.is_file():
                print(i)
            elif i.is_dir():
                subfolder(i)
    elif line[0] == "D":
         p = Path(str(line[2:]))
         contents = p.iterdir()
         for i in contents:
             print(i)
             if i.is_file():
                 print(i)
    else:
         print("ERROR")

infile.close()
```

When I run this code, I receive the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmelu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Project 1.py", line 32, in <module>
    for i in contents:
  File "C:\Users\jmelu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1059, in iterdir
    for name in self._accessor.listdir(self):
  File "C:\Users\jmelu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 387, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Test\\Project1\n'
```

Previously, this same exact code worked earlier and it works on other computers as well.  I tried reinstalling pathlib but to no success.  I am on python 3.6.2.

Comment: You didn't take the line breaks off.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by line breaks?  I'm new to this and don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading your paths from a file with a path per line, but you didn't strip the newlines from each string, so you're looking for files that include a newline character, `\n`. As your error message notes, the invalid path was:

```
'C:\\Test\\Project1\n' <-- Single slash followed by n; directories are double slash separated
```

Strip them off as you read, and you'll be fine:

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.rstrip("\r\n")  # Removes all trailing carriage returns and newlines
    if line[0] == "R":
```

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot that I had a blank line in my text file that I didn't even consider in my input.